# Moving photos into app memory

Tags: android, photo

Within my Android app I need to allow the user to Select multiple images from the phone's Photos (*which I can already do*) and then **MOVE** (**not COPY**) the photos from where they currently are located into the app's specific data directory.

EDIT:  Code added for review:

```
public class GalleryImagePicker extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
Context cntxt = Defines.contextGlobal;

private static final int DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH_QUALITY = 400;
public static int minWidthQuality = DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH_QUALITY;

private ArrayList<String> imagesPathList;
private ArrayList<Uri> imagesUri;

private LinearLayout lnrImages;
private Button btnAddPhotos;
private Button btnSaveImages;
private Bitmap yourbitmap;
private Bitmap resized;
private final int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1;
private ImageView targetImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.galleryimagepicker);
    lnrImages = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lnrImages);

    btnAddPhotos = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddPhotos);
    btnAddPhotos.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnSaveImages = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSaveImages);
    btnSaveImages.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAddPhotos:
            /*Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryImagePicker.this,CustomPhotoGalleryActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);*/
            Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryImagePicker.this,CustomPhotoGalleryActivity.class);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
            break;

        case R.id.btnSaveImages:
            if(imagesPathList != null)
            {
                if(imagesPathList.size() >= 1) {
                    //Toast.makeText(GalleryImagePicker.this, imagesPathList.size() + " no of images are selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String[] stringArray = imagesPathList.toArray(new String[0]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
                        String ThisImgPath = stringArray[i];
                        String PicName = ThisImgPath;
                        if (SystemIOFile.exists(PicName)) {
                            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
                            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ThisImgPath, bmOptions);
                            Uri ThisUri = getImageUri(cntxt, bm);
                            bm = decodeBitmap(cntxt, ThisUri, bmOptions.inSampleSize);

                            Boolean HOLD = true;
                        }

                        Boolean HOLD = true;
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(GalleryImagePicker.this, imagesPathList.size() + " no of image are selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(GalleryImagePicker.this," no images are selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Other code:

```
public class CustomPhotoGalleryActivity extends Activity {

private GridView grdImages;
private Button btnSelect;

private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private String[] arrPath;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private int ids[];
private int count;


/**
 * Overrides methods
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_gallery);
    grdImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdImages);
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    grdImages.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagecursor.close();

    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                }
            }

            if (cnt == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select at least one image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("data", selectImages);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    super.onBackPressed();
}

/**
 * Class method
 */

/**
 * This method used to set bitmap.
 * @param iv represented ImageView 
 * @param id represented id
 */

private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv, final int id) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            iv.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }.execute();
}


/**
 * List adapter
 * @author tasol
 */

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_item, null);
            holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
            holder.chkImage = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.chkImage.setId(position);
        holder.imgThumb.setId(position);
        holder.chkImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imgThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = holder.chkImage.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    holder.chkImage.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    holder.chkImage.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            setBitmap(holder.imgThumb, ids[position]);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        holder.chkImage.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}


/**
 * Inner class
 * @author tasol
 */
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgThumb;
    CheckBox chkImage;
    int id;
}
```

}

Being an Android novice and using code from web postings I'll have to ask.
Isn't the above code already creating a custom UI?
If so, then how do I acquire the original photo URI or fully-pathed file name so as to perform the **COPY/DELETE** ?

**EDIT #2:**
OK, let me continue to display my ignorance...

In my GalleryImagePicker code, in the OnActivity where   case R.id.btnSaveImages:  I have a **imagesPathList()**
When I enter that part of the code that list contains the 'paths' of the selected photos.

Real-world examples of imagesPathList() contents:

```
imagesPathList(0) = /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20180419_095352.jpg 
imagesPathList(1) = /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20180419_095359.jpg
```

Assuming that I have somehow managed to get READ/WRITE permissions set, can't I use those pathed filenames to **COPY/DELETE**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Create your own UI for allowing the user to select multiple photos, where you are scanning the filesystem for photos to show, by whatever algorithm you wish to use for deciding what is and is not a photo. You will not be able to use `MediaStore` or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or similar things, as you can only work with files for which you have write access.

Step #2: Set your `minSdkVersion` to 26 (Android 8.0), then [call `Files.move()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Files.html#move) to move the file from its original location to your desired location. Or, if you are willing to say that "move" is "copy, then delete the original", you can use classic Java I/O copy-the-file code, then `delete()` the original `File`, and your `minSdkVersion` does not matter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll probably use the COPY and then DELETE method since my userbase can possibly include a few older Android units.

Comment: But how do I specify the original photo file and its original location in order to do the COPY/DELETE?   By its URI or its fully-pathed filename or what?

Comment: @Dhugalmac: You do not have a `Uri`. You cannot work with any `Uri`, because you may not have any means to delete that content. That is why my Step #1 says that you have to create your own UI that works directly with the filesystem, so you can limit your scope to only files that you can read and write. Then, you have `File` objects on which you can call `delete()` (when appropriate).

Comment: Aren't I already creating the custom UI with the code I'm using - shown in the EDIT above?

Comment: @Dhugalmac: Yes, you are. However, you are using `MediaStore`, which I said in Step #1 that you could not use. This is why I keep repeating that  you need to create your own UI **that works directly with the filesystem, so you can limit  your scope to only files that you can read and write**.

Comment: Keep in mind that I am pretty new to Android development - so please keep explanations SIMPLE.   OK, if I cannot use MediaStore, how else can I approach getting done what I need and so **that it works directly with the filesystem, thereby limiting the scope to only files that I can read and write**

Comment: @Dhugalmac: "so please keep explanations SIMPLE" -- what you are doing is not necessarily simple. You are welcome to write some code that looks for files on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) that match your requirements, as you can arrange to hold the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission that you would need to be able to delete the file. You can use [standard Java recipes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13444760/115145) to scan a directory (e.g., `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`) for files of interest.